# DQL delete from multiple tables (doctrine)

Tags: doctrine, multiple-tables

I need to perform DQL delete from multiple related tables.
In SQL it is something like this:

```
  DELETE r1,r2 
  FROM ComRealty_objects r1, com_realty_objects_phones r2 
  WHERE r1.id IN (10,20) AND r2.id_object IN (10,20)
```

I need to perform this statement using DQL, but I'm stuck on this. :(

```
<?php
$dql = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->delete('phones, comrealtyobjects')
     ->from('ComRealtyObjects comrealtyobjects')
     ->from('ComRealtyObjectsPhones phones')
     ->whereIn("comrealtyobjects.id", $ids)
     ->whereIn("phones.id_object", $ids);
echo($dql->getSqlQuery());
?>
```

But DQL parser gives me this result:

```
DELETE FROM `com_realty_objects_phones`, `ComRealty_objects` 
WHERE (`id` IN (?) AND `id_object` IN (?))
```

Searching google and stack overflow I found this(useful) topic: 
[What is the syntax for a multi-table delete on a MySQL database using Doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247905/what-is-the-syntax-for-a-multi-table-delete-on-a-mysql-database-using-doctrine)
But this is not exactly my case - there was delete from single table.

If there is a way to override DQL parser behaviour? Or is there maybe some other way to delete records from multiple tables using doctrine?

Note: If you are using doctrine behaviours(Doctrine_Record_Generator), you need first to initialize those tables using `Doctrine_Core::initializeModels()` to perform DQL operations on them.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$dql = Doctrine_Query::create()
     ->from('ComRealtyObjects comrealtyobjects')
     ->from('ComRealtyObjectsPhones phones')
     ->whereIn("comrealtyobjects.id", $ids)
     ->whereIn("phones.id_object", $ids);
$result= $dql->execute();
$result->delete();
```

and tell me how it goes

Answer (score 0):

If they're related so that $ids will remove both:

```
 ->delete()
 ->from('ComRealtyObjects c, c.ComRealtyObjectsPhones p')
 ->whereIn('c.id', '?', $ids)
```

That should do the job.